# Questions about Transformer evaluation part

Tags: python, deep-learning, transformer-model

And this is the time series prediction of Transformer

I'm trying to train the model, but I got `Validation loss: nan` , `R_p=nan`

when I check the train_loss, I found the loss function is nothing wrong, but the `test_loss and val_loss are nan`

I could not figure out which part is wrong.

```
t0: previous t0 data points to predict from

N: number of data points
```

```
t0 = 2073
future = 231

def Dp(y_pred,y_true,q):
    return max([q*(y_pred-y_true),(q-1)*(y_pred-y_true)])

def Rp_num_den(y_preds,y_trues,q):
    numerator = np.sum([Dp(y_pred,y_true,q) for y_pred,y_true in zip(y_preds,y_trues)])
    denominator = np.sum([np.abs(y_true) for y_true in y_trues])
    return numerator,denominator


def train_epoch(model, train_dl, t0):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    n = 0
    for step, (x, y, attention_masks) in enumerate(train_dl):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = model(x.to(device), y.to(device), attention_masks[0].to(device))
        loss = criterion(output.squeeze()[:, (t0 - 1):(t0 + future - 1)], y.to(device)[:, t0:])  # not missing data
        # loss = criterion(output.squeeze()[:,(t0-1-10):(t0+24-1-10)],y.cuda()[:,(t0-10):]) # missing data
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        train_loss += (loss.detach().cpu().item() * x.shape[0])
        n += x.shape[0]
    return train_loss / n


def eval_epoch(model, val_dl, t0):
    model.eval()
    eval_loss = 0
    n = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for step, (x, y, attention_masks) in enumerate(val_dl):
            output = model(x.to(device), y.to(device), attention_masks[0].to(device))
            loss = criterion(output.squeeze()[:, (t0 - 1):(t0 + future - 1)], y.to(device)[:, t0:])  # not missing dataloss = {Tensor} tensor(nan, device='cuda:0')
            # loss = criterion(output.squeeze()[:,(t0-1-10):(t0+24-1-10)],y.cuda()[:,(t0-10):]) # missing data

            eval_loss += (loss.detach().cpu().item() * x.shape[0])
            n += x.shape[0]

    return eval_loss / n


def test_epoch(model, test_dl, t0):
    with torch.no_grad():
        predictions = []
        observations = []

        model.eval()
        for step, (x, y, attention_masks) in enumerate(test_dl):
            output = model(x.to(device), y.to(device), attention_masks[0].to(device))

            for p, o in zip(output.squeeze()[:, (t0 - 1):(t0 + future - 1)].cpu().numpy().tolist(),
                            y.to(device)[:, t0:].cpu().numpy().tolist()):  # not missing data
                # for p,o in zip(output.squeeze()[:,(t0-1-10):(t0+24-1-10)].cpu().numpy().tolist(),y.cuda()[:,(t0-10):].cpu().numpy().tolist()): # missing data

                predictions.append(p)
                observations.append(o)

        num = 0
        den = 0
        for y_preds, y_trues in zip(predictions, observations):
            num_i, den_i = Rp_num_den(y_preds, y_trues, .5)
            num += num_i
            den += den_i
        Rp = (2 * num) / den

        print(Rp)

    return Rp


train_epoch_loss = []
eval_epoch_loss = []
Rp_best = 10
model_save_path = 'ConvTransformer_nologsparse.pth'
for e, epoch in enumerate(range(epochs)):
    train_loss = []
    eval_loss = []

    l_t = train_epoch(model, train_dl, t0)
    train_loss.append(l_t)

    l_e = eval_epoch(model, val_dl, t0)
    eval_loss.append(l_e)

    Rp = test_epoch(model, test_dl, t0)

    if Rp_best > Rp:
        Rp_best = Rp

    train_epoch_loss.append(np.mean(train_loss))
    eval_epoch_loss.append(np.mean(eval_loss))

    print("Epoch {}: Train loss: {} \t Validation loss: {} \t R_p={}".format(e,
                                                                             np.mean(train_loss),
                                                                             np.mean(eval_loss), Rp))
print("Rp best={}".format(Rp_best))
```

output:

```
Epoch 94: Train loss: 0.5179461240768433     Validation loss: nan    R_p=nan
nan
Epoch 95: Train loss: 0.5195054411888123     Validation loss: nan    R_p=nan
nan
Epoch 96: Train loss: 0.5231510996818542     Validation loss: nan    R_p=nan
nan
Epoch 97: Train loss: 0.520694375038147      Validation loss: nan    R_p=nan
nan
Epoch 98: Train loss: 0.525615394115448      Validation loss: nan    R_p=nan
nan
Epoch 99: Train loss: 0.5247501134872437     Validation loss: nan    R_p=nan
Rp best=10
```

Comment: where have you defined `criterion`?

Comment: I just define criterion for MSE